# My other site appearing in the path of my URLs in Google Webmaster Tools crawl errors

Tags: google, error

Google is not fetching this page http://www.ctdraincleaning.net/andover-drain-cleaning/ (along with others) Not only that... it is coming up as a crawl error as
http://www.ctdraincleaning.net/andover-drain-cleaning/www.brightstartstudios.com

brightstartstudios(dot)com is my other website... but I don't know why it's showing up after as a crawl error after the other site.
Please help... I have no clue whats going on.

Heres what it looks like:

[image: Crawl Errors]

Comment: BTW- adorable photo!!

Comment: How do you know that Google isn't fetching some of your pages?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the source code of your website:

```
<a target="new" href="www.brightstartstudios.com">
```

That is missing the `http://`.  It should be:

```
<a target="new" href="http://www.brightstartstudios.com">
```

Google is interpreting what you currently have as a *relative* link.   You need to include the `http://` to make it absolute to another site.   It isn't just Google that would have this problem; if you clicked on that link your browser would also get an error.

Comment: Hmmm... I am actually trying to crawl the www.ctdraincleaning.net/andover-drain-cleaning/ and it is not showing when I do this search - site:www.ctdraincleaning.net. So are you saying I need to change the source code on brightstartstudios so it wont show up in the crawl error path of my other site?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before. It is likely a bad link on a scraper site somewhere and Google followed it. Often the software tools that they use have weird bugs in them that make bad links, references, and user agents and so on. You will see this again.

For what it is worth, do not worry about 404 errors that do not exist. These things happen. Just let them a be and it will all work out okay. I promise.

Comment: I wish I could forget about it but google is not fetching that webpage and I need it to fetch about 60+ others.  Instead its coming up as a crawl error with an additional website after it. Like this:
http://w ww.ctdraincleaning.net/andover-drain-cleaning/www.brightstartstudios.com

Comment: @SabrinaOlenik Have you tried *Fetch as Google* in Google Webmaster Tools? Also Stephen Ostermiller brings up a valid point that I forgot about. Make sure your links are correct everywhere on your site. We have all made this mistake at least once in our lives. It is easy enough to make a mistake with so much detail these days.

Comment: Thanks for your help as well! I had a bad link in my footer.  :S